# How to use existing go daddy certificate for nodejs application

Tags: express

We have developed a single page application (static html files) and planned for deployment into QA and LIVE. It is using backend as Nodejs (Express js) as hosting server.

We are already having godaddy certificate authority g2 with other applications which wanted to use the same for the above developed nodejs based application.

How can use existing godaddy certificate with nodejs developed application for deployment testing like QA?

Comment: do you want to add SSL certificate on your QA server ?

Comment: Yes. Also wanted to read existing go daddy certificate through express server in QA for testing...

Comment: @SaurabhMistry ...any help?

Comment: I have used FREE Certbot SSL certificate in my website  and used same SSL certificate for multiple subdomain , but I don't have idea about GODADDY certificate

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Also can you please provide the details how it is created and integrated with node js server with required certificates?

Comment: you can get more info about certbot here : https://certbot.eff.org/